# watir is slow with long dropdown menus

Tags: watir

It takes about two seconds for Watir ("classic" Watir) to select an option from dropdown menu that has about 250 options. Is there any way to make this faster?

(Two seconds may not sound like much, but with repeated "stress tests" this becomes a little annoying...)

I already tested "browser.speed = :zippy", but it has no effect on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to speed things up would be to generate automatic html ID attributes for each option and then locate by id. For example:

```
<select id="options">
  <option id="option1">First Option</option>
  <option id="option2">Second Option</option>
  ...
  <option id="optionx">X Option</option>
</select>
```

And then select like this:

```
browser.option(:id => "option2").select
```